# regex (or any other method) for finding the number of newline charcters in the text the user inputs in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i need to count the number of newline characters (or whatever is inserted when the user press the return key) in the value of a textarea. I think i should use a regular expression, but i'm really bad ad it and i don't know what i should look for.

```
<textarea id='countIt'></textarea>

var value = $('#countIt').val();

 //need help from here
```

Of course if there is a smarter method, feel free to suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `value.split(/\n/).length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
var breaksArray = value.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/);
```